# How to add link for bullets in Readme md file

Tags: markdown, readme

How to add a link for bullets in Readme md file. I do not want to paste the link rather use something like this:

[Atomic:](https://github.com/MazinIsmail/JavaLearnings/tree/master/src/main/concurrency/com/atomic/learnings)

But however, the above syntax don't work for 'li' tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it the following way

`* [Atomic:](https://github.com/MazinIsmail/JavaLearnings/tree/master/src/main/concurrency/com/atomic/learnings)`

- [Atomic:](https://github.com/MazinIsmail/JavaLearnings/tree/master/src/main/concurrency/com/atomic/learnings)

  - [Atomic](https://github.com/MazinIsmail/JavaLearnings/tree/master/src/main/concurrency/com/atomic/learnings)

To add subpoints, add two spaces before the asterisk symbol.

Comment: What if I want to create a second-level bullet point with a link?

Comment: @MazinIsmail just add two spaces before the symbol