# How to add links for ordered list in Readme md file

Tags: markdown, readme

How to add a link for ordered list 'ol' items in Readme md file. I do not want to paste the link rather use something like this:

1. [GSMA](https://www.gsma.com/esim/esim-specification)

   [TCA (SAIP)](https://trustedconnectivityalliance.org/technology-library-sim-specifications)

It seems that above syntax don't work for 'li' tag (ol/ul items).

There is [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64132092/5073483) for unordered list 'ul' items. But wanted to check how to achieve the similar for ordered list items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also face the same problem and found help [here](https://github.com/emn178/markdown/blob/master/README.md).

### Summary:

Instead of 'ol' (& 'li') tags, try something like below:

```
<BR>i am talking about below things:
1. [GSMA](https://www.gsma.com/esim/esim-specification)
2. [TCA (SAIP)](https://trustedconnectivityalliance.org/technology-library-sim-specifications)
<BR>bla bla bla
```

Later `<BR>` tag will ensure that your ordered list is closed & will work as a workaround for `<\ol>`